# i'm trying to make a "link" in my php page so it make changes in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

so i'm trying to make the link pop up a javascript message so when the users clicks "yes"
it adds or removes a row from my database
without redirecting to another php page.
is that possible using php?

Comment: You can try ajax.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I referred you to another question and its answers; it is relevant to you, because your command from your Javascript popup to your server will, in fact, be a kind of form post.

Comment: AJAX is the way of doing it. Call your php which communicates with your db.